# WPF button style and template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templatebinding

So i have the button and its style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BaseButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"  />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1FA3FF"  />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonStyle"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">          
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1FA3EB"  />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"  />
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="My text" />
```

It works fine and i have the following results (aquamarine background isn't part of Button, it belongs to Window):

[image]

But then i want to replace button's content and change my style so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonStyle"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">          
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1FA3EB"  />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"  />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="√" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and now my button becomes awful:

[image]

As you can see my button lost its borders and background and it doesn't change its view when mouse is over it. Where am i wrong and what should i do to prevent it?

**UPD**

when i do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonStyle"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">          
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1FA3EB"  />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"  />
    <Setter Property="Content" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="√" />
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

then i get this result:

[image]

As you can see this is similar to the firstresult, where the check mark is missing

Comment: It's because you changed template so you removed default view for the `Button` and replaced it with `StackPanel`. BTW you can put this `StackPanel` directly as content, without changing template. `Content` can be anything, not only text

Comment: but when i place StackPanel as content i can not bind content correctly((

Answer (score 5):

The look and functionality of the default `Button` is defined in the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` (you can find that in the [Button Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753328(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN). As you changed the `ControlTemplate`, the default look and behaviour is now gone and replaced with your plain `StackPanel` and `TextBlock` elements.

When providing a new `ControlTemplate` for controls, it is a good idea to start with the default `ControlTemplate` and make small changes until you have your desired look. Here is a slight extension to your `Style` that provides some basic mouse over functionality:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="√" />
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You can find out more about `ControlTemplate`s from the [`ControlTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: MSDN has changed the location of the button styles page

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @PeterM... I have replaced the broken link now.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to change the content of the button, you can do it this way:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
    <!-- This is the content -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="√" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonTextBinding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This way you don't loose the basic styling. The button content property is an object, so it takes anything.
The moment you alter the control template of a button, everything about background, border, mouse over, pressed states etc. is lost. The best way to restyle any WPF control is to take the basic template from MSDN and modify it, rather than starting from scratch. You can find the button template here:

[.NET 4.5 Button template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx)